# How to correctly expose a kubernetes deployment running locally in kind on MacOS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx, kind

I am having some trouble in exposing a simple nginx deployment on a locally running Kind cluster on a Macbook.

I have a simple nginx deployment and I have tried to use `kubectl expose` or create a service object manually in order to access port 80 and verify the nginx deployment is accessible from outside the cluster. I've tried a number of service types (`ClusterIP`, `NodePort`, `LoadBalancer`) but I just can't do it successfully. I'm fairly sure the service type I actually want is `NodePort` (it would `LoadBalancer` if I had my cluster in the cloud (AWS, GCP, etc)) and I'm pretty sure I am using the correct IP for the node (the internal IP of my only node).

```
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION    CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kind-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   2d4h   v1.27.3   172.18.0.2    <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)   6.4.16-linuxkit   containerd://1.7.1
```

I found [this article](https://mauilion.dev/posts/kind-metallb/) and it says that the kubernetes network is not exposed to the Macbook host due to how Docker runs on MacOS. I've verified that my deployment works as I used a port forward to access the deployed container and can see the default "Welcome to nginx" page.

Is this article correct? And if so, how can I expose the deployment and verify it can be accessed externally?